# Could not find drawing tag. How to post drawing questions?

Tags: discussion

How do I post the drawing questions without the drawing tag?

Comment: You need to be more clear. Do you not want the tag? Looking for an alternative? Asking for why it's not working? You need to tell us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to create tags during closed beta, even without the reputation normally required.  Just type the name of the tag you wish to use (e.g. "drawing").

As the beta progresses, the community will review and discuss how we will use tags, and what types of tags are or are not acceptable, but "drawing" seems like it is probably a good one.

Comment: Wait? The question is really confusing - is it asking for an alternative to the tag, why the tag can't be created, or what?

Comment: @Zizouz212 Seems fairly clear to me... there is no [tag:drawing].  I assumed the OP was looking to add one.  But perhaps I'm over-simplifying it?

Comment: I hear you, but what's confusing is "post question *without* the drawing tag" - what's that supposed to mean.

Comment: @Zizouz212 confused probably because you didn't read the title of the question along with the body? Isn't the title pretty clear?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius I think that is exactly what's confusing me - do you want the tag or not?

Answer (score 2):

You can not create tags on the mobile version of the website or within the mobile app.

If you're on a mobile device you must use something such as the "Request Desktop Version" in Chrome, or choose the "full site" option at the footer of the mobile page.

On the full site, you'll be able to create new tags.